# mysql-server deleted eachday at 7o'clock

Tags: mysql, debian, mariadb

I've a big problem with my private server on debian 7

Since febuary I've run a php5/mysql (maria DB)/apache2 server for some personal website.

But since yesterday, at 7 o'clock the mysql server doesn't work.

I connect to my server and type "mysql": Mysql command not found

I go on aptitude and I see the mariaDB is not installed !
Make a apt-get update
and reinstall mariaDB.

All is fine and work.

But the morning, I see I have the same problem. At 7 o'clock the mysql server (the mariaDB) is not installed. Type mysql return Mysql command not found.
Go to aptitude and unable to install mariaDB.
To install it I have to apt-get update then install mariaDB and all work fine..

But I think tomorrow at 7 o'clock the mysql server go out...

Any ideas?

thanks!

ps: sorry I'm not at home and I have not the precise time when the mysql is deleted and not all the correct error.. But if you have a similar problem plz help me !

**Edit1:**
My /var/log/dpkg.log

```
2015-04-21 04:17:48 startup packages remove
2015-04-21 04:17:48 status installed mariadb-server:all 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:48 remove mariadb-server:all 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy <none>
2015-04-21 04:17:48 status half-configured mariadb-server:all 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:48 status half-installed mariadb-server:all 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:48 status config-files mariadb-server:all 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:48 status config-files mariadb-server:all 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:48 status config-files mariadb-server:all 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:48 status not-installed mariadb-server:all <none>
2015-04-21 04:17:48 status installed mariadb-server-5.5:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:48 remove mariadb-server-5.5:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy <none>
2015-04-21 04:17:48 status half-configured mariadb-server-5.5:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:49 status half-installed mariadb-server-5.5:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:50 status triggers-pending man-db:amd64 2.6.2-1
2015-04-21 04:17:50 status half-installed mariadb-server-5.5:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:50 status config-files mariadb-server-5.5:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:50 status config-files mariadb-server-5.5:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:50 status installed mariadb-client-5.5:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:50 remove mariadb-client-5.5:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy <none>
2015-04-21 04:17:50 status half-configured mariadb-client-5.5:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:50 status half-installed mariadb-client-5.5:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:50 status half-installed mariadb-client-5.5:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:50 status config-files mariadb-client-5.5:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:50 status config-files mariadb-client-5.5:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:50 status installed mariadb-client-core-5.5:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:50 remove mariadb-client-core-5.5:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy <none>
2015-04-21 04:17:50 status half-configured mariadb-client-core-5.5:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:51 status half-installed mariadb-client-core-5.5:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:51 status half-installed mariadb-client-core-5.5:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:51 status config-files mariadb-client-core-5.5:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:51 status config-files mariadb-client-core-5.5:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:51 status config-files mariadb-client-core-5.5:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:51 status not-installed mariadb-client-core-5.5:amd64 <none>
2015-04-21 04:17:51 status installed mariadb-server-core-5.5:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:51 remove mariadb-server-core-5.5:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy <none>
2015-04-21 04:17:51 status half-configured mariadb-server-core-5.5:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:51 status half-installed mariadb-server-core-5.5:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:51 status half-installed mariadb-server-core-5.5:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:51 status config-files mariadb-server-core-5.5:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:51 status config-files mariadb-server-core-5.5:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:51 status config-files mariadb-server-core-5.5:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:51 status not-installed mariadb-server-core-5.5:amd64 <none>
2015-04-21 04:17:51 status installed libmariadbclient18:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:51 status installed libmariadbclient18:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:52 status installed libmariadbclient18:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:52 status installed libmariadbclient18:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:52 status installed libmariadbclient18:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:52 status installed libmariadbclient18:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:52 status installed libmariadbclient18:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:52 status installed libmariadbclient18:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:52 remove libmariadbclient18:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy <none>
2015-04-21 04:17:52 status half-configured libmariadbclient18:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:52 status half-installed libmariadbclient18:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:52 status config-files libmariadbclient18:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:52 status config-files libmariadbclient18:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:52 trigproc man-db:amd64 2.6.2-1 <none>
2015-04-21 04:17:52 status half-configured man-db:amd64 2.6.2-1
2015-04-21 04:17:53 status installed man-db:amd64 2.6.2-1
2015-04-21 04:17:53 startup archives unpack
2015-04-21 04:17:53 upgrade libmysqlclient18:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy 5.5.43-0+deb7u1
2015-04-21 04:17:53 status half-configured libmysqlclient18:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:53 status unpacked libmysqlclient18:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:53 status half-installed libmysqlclient18:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:53 status half-installed libmysqlclient18:amd64 5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy
2015-04-21 04:17:54 status unpacked libmysqlclient18:amd64 5.5.43-0+deb7u1
2015-04-21 04:17:54 status unpacked libmysqlclient18:amd64 5.5.43-0+deb7u1
2015-04-21 04:17:54 startup packages configure
2015-04-21 04:17:54 configure libmysqlclient18:amd64 5.5.43-0+deb7u1 <none>
2015-04-21 04:17:54 status unpacked libmysqlclient18:amd64 5.5.43-0+deb7u1
2015-04-21 04:17:54 status half-configured libmysqlclient18:amd64 5.5.43-0+deb7u1
2015-04-21 04:17:54 status installed libmysqlclient18:amd64 5.5.43-0+deb7u1
```

There are a few cron on the server but only for refreshing some data.

But this morning when I try to reinstall mariaDB Aptitude give me some error (don't remember the exact term) and it was unable to install mariaDB.
For install I have to apt-get update and then go to aptitude and select package. it return me some error with 3 options (Examine, Valid and other don't remember option:( )

If I don't find a solution this night, I screenshot tomorrow morning if mariaDB go out..

But if anyone have a solution I'll take it !

thanks !

**Edit2**

some screenshot take this morning:

Before execute `apt-get update`:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4gex.png
We show the package have no version installed et no version available

After execute `apt-get update`:
[8 Screenshots here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5BdK.png)

We show some red error, with suggest. The suggest 6 keep make nothing if I apply it. 
The suggest 1 downgrade, dowgrade libmysqlclient18 and install mariaDB..
But dpkg remove mariaDB all the morning...

Please help me :)

Comment: This feels like a question for server fault, but have you looked at the log files? `/var/log/dpkg.log` is probably the relevant one. Are there any cron jobs scheduled on the server? Does installing mariadb cause conflicts or broken packages?

Comment: You say "unable to install"?  Could this mean that is installed?  Yet not accessible?

Comment: Unable to install => I'm unable to select package in aptitude. he told me that there is no package to install. But after apt-get update I can select the package and install it.. You can see my first post edit for more information. It's strange because before apt-get update the package in aptitude view have no version for mariaDB package (<none> <none>) but after apt-get update the version is ok (<none> <5.5.42+maria-1~wheezy>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, my problem.

I follow [this tutorial](https://mespotesgeek.fr/configuration-et-securisation-dun-serveur-linux-debian-partie-1/) for setting up my server and he force the security installation without take the mariaDB repo.